# Is Zenbook's QHD+ display working with Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, display, laptop

I consider buying an [Asus Zenbook](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZENBOOK-UX305FA/) UX305FA but it is hard to find any reliable information regarding usability of the QHD+ display. Does it make sense with Ubuntu? All information, I found is rather vague or outdated. Can anybody report experiences with that machine / display and Ubuntu?

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX305FA
Ubuntu: 14.04

Answer (score 2):

I have a Dell XPS13 9343 with a QHD display (3200x1800) and use Ubuntu Gnome.

Most applications run well, but Firefox struggles to keep the resolution consistent. I use an add-on AutoHiDPI which helps, but if the window is resized or moved, it resets. So I keep the add-ons tab open so that I can disable/re-enable the addon to correct it.

A few older applications have strange half-height edit boxes, but again, resizing windows often sorts them out.

If you use Remmina for RDP access, there is currently no ability to scale the remote display, so for me, accessing a Windows server via Remmina gives a minute window.

Current Linux versions will only handle HiDPI settings across all monitors, so if you plug in an ordinary external monitor, it is assumed to be HiDPI and so windows are massive. When Wayland is finally released, this will be resolved as it enables each monitor to have its own HiDPI settings.

In summary, today things on HiDPI displays are OK in general, with a few older apps that can be a challenge, but things will improve as time moves on, especially as more & more devices use hi-res monitors.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that Ubuntu works well with the display of UX305FA (see also [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ia8ta/review_of_ubuntu_on_asus_ux305fa/)). The computer has the integrated Intel graphics which is using the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` which is rather buggy. It causes much complications in many programs and applications. However, its substitute `modesetting` package has its pros and cons too. Etc flickering screen with videos and interactive websites like Google Plus in the former. I purged the former so I use instead the latter package which works better for me (since hate epileptic views) but has its complications, for instance with Matlab (font rendering; ...). As a summary

- no complete keybindings in Ubuntu with the `modesetting` package; etc no no brightness control with the keys F5/F6 but can be done.
- `xserver-xorg-video-intel` - possible flickering of the screen with interactive media but solutions for other UI bugs etc F5/F6 for brightness adjustments exist.

Conclusion: Zenbook is more robust than Macbook for Ubuntu; QHD+ resolution works great, also with an external display; graphic drivers can be a source of pain (Intel and NVidia) but the development team is working with the `modesetting` package for the coming releases (not sure when); however, no possibility to update firmwares on the Ubuntu side; most Zenbooks are designed nowadays for Windows 10 so you may want to keep Windows 10 as dual-boot on your system.

Related: [Review of Ubuntu on Asus UX305FA](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/3ia8ta/review_of_ubuntu_on_asus_ux305fa/)
Hardwares tested: UX305FA, UX303UA
Ubuntu: 16.04